# How to prevent closing of jQuery UI selectmenu on click to other element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI selectmenu dropdown menu. On it is some element. Dropdown menu closes when you click to this element.
How to prevent closing of jQuery UI selectmenu on click to other element?

Please take a look to http://jsfiddle.net/98beco3h/ and you'll understand what I want to do.

```
$('.month_select').selectmenu({
    open: function( event, ui ) {
      $( ".year-spinner_block" ).position({
        of: $( ".ui-selectmenu-open" ),
        my: 'center bottom',
        at: 'center bottom'
      });
    },
    close: function() {
        $( ".year-spinner_block" ).css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'left': '-9999px'
        });
    }
});
$('.year-spinner').spinner();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the document mousedown event (set on open) from firing. Something like:

```
$( document ).off( "mousedown" );
```

See the fiddle for basic idea. You will need to add some mechanism to close the menu yourself.

http://jsfiddle.net/98beco3h/4/